# how to find is there a file open using c#

Tags: c#

how to find is there a file is open or not and if open then then find its fullpath or directory.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Enumerate all files and then find the first open one? Or enumerate all open files, like FileMon does?

Comment: What object are you starting with? Do you have a filestream pointing to the file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “open”? Normally I would understand it to mean that “the operating system holds a handle on the file” and/or “the file has a read-lock or a write-lock on it”, but a feeling tells me that’s not what you mean. Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: I don't see what so hard to understand: 'In C# How can I find if a file is in use by another program, and if it is how can I get it's full file path?'

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply more information.

All the File handling classes are in System.IO. You will want to use File or FileInfo.

Answer (score 1):

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
try
{
    stream.ReadByte();
    //file is not open
}
catch (IOException)
{
    //it is open

}
```

Explanation: Open the file, try to read a byte, if it can't we know its either open or readonly.

And to get the full path you can use:

```
fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path);
```